# Python PATH .is_file() evaluates symlink as a file

Tags: linux, python-3.x, symlink

In my Python3 program, I take a bunch of paths and do things based on what they are.  When I evaluate the following symlinks (snippet):

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1  513  513        5 Aug 19 10:56 console -> ttyS0
lrwxrwxrwx  1  513  513       11 Aug 19 10:56 core -> /proc/kcore
lrwxrwxrwx  1  513  513       13 Aug 19 10:56 fd -> /proc/self/fd
```

the results are:

```
symlink   console -> ttyS0
file      core -> /proc/kcore
symlink   console -> ttyS0
```

It evaluates *core* as if it were a file (vs a symlink).  What is the best way for me to evaluate it as a symlink  vs a file? code below

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path

def filetype(filein):
    print(filein)
    if Path(filein).is_file():
        return "file"
    if Path(filein).is_symlink():
        return  "symlink"
    else:
        return "doesn't match anything"

if __name__ == "__main__":
file = sys.argv[1]
print(str(file))
print(filetype(file))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `is_file` is intended to answer the question "if I open this name, will I open a file". For a symlink, the answer is "yes" if the target is a file, hence the return value.

If you want to know if the name is a symlink, ask `is_symlink`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The answer was  as simple as flipping the order of the evaluation (check to see if it was a symlink first, then check to see if it is a file.  That did it.